# Need to solve this Error

Tags: c, ms-access, oledb, jet, oledbconnection

Using Oledb to connect to an MS Access DB.

I get the following error when the Open Function of the OleDbConnection class is called

"The 'Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0' provider is not registered on the local machine."

Comment: There are tons of Google results for this: http://bit.ly/idlWdE What have you already tried?

Comment: In that case, it sounds like you should... register the `Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0` provider on your local machine.

Comment: Are you using a 64-bit OS? If so, Jet won't work; see [here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w7itproappcompat/thread/14041b74-6ca6-49be-af90-d8ff3f962724);

Comment: Or, he could download the 64-bit version of the ACE and install that.

Answer (score 1):

I guess your OS 64-bit but Microsoft Jet does not support 64-bit. TO resolve this you need force your application to use the 32 bit change the target CPU to x86 in the advanced compiler options.

Please check out this [link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/adodotnetdataproviders/thread/45aa44dd-0e6f-42e5-a9d6-9be5c5c8fcd1) for more details.

Comment: If you mean Jet 4.0, then, no, it doesn't have a 64-bit version. But applications compiled for x86 can run on a 64-bit Windows and use 32-bit Jet. And the 64-bit ACE can provide access to Jet 4.0 data files (as well as ACE data files, i.e., ACCDBs). It's downloadable for free.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem occur all of a sudden and it wasn't a "Jet" problem as it previously worked, and then stopped working.  As it turned out, the application pool that the site was running under had "Enable 32-bit applications" changed to "False".  When I changed back to "True", the OleDb error went away.